# unix gcc file overwrite

Tags: c, unix, gcc, nano

I did something really stupid during my development.

I wrote on terminal

```
gcc source.c -o source.c
```

Instead of

```
gcc source.c -o source.bin
```

Or something like that

I was editing the file using nano.Is there any way to restore it ?
Either using any possible autosaves or something like decompile .?

Comment: `nano`, if configured so, creates backups of edited files, for example, if you were editing `foo.c`, it creates `~foo.c` (it's a hidden file IIRC). You may be able to get something out of that.

Comment: check hidden files using `ls -lart`. You are providing both names same. check `gcc source.c -o source.c`. change object name.

Comment: @Dimitris LoL... you can recover your file only if you system saved a backup file. in the directory where code is present try this command `~$:  ls *~`  check if you code is present.

Answer (score 0):

I did that myself not that long ago.    Luckily I still had my emacs editor opened so could just re-save the file.   You can't recover the source from the object file unfortunately.   Check around in the source file's directory for files named with special characters, perhaps beginning with "."

Comment: There are no files starting with . , ls - part as you guys said, but there are no files :(

Comment: Well it's a long shot but you could also check in your system's directory for temporary files